# macros with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, macros

I've been developing application which uses logging mechanism, and I implemented sort of printf function which takes various number of arguments and prints to log certain message, what I want is to add a function name to this function, but I dont what to write this argument in each function call.

So I decided to write a macros, turns out it not so easy

```
#define WriteToLogParams(szMessage, nLogLevel, param1, param2) WriteToLogParamsFunc(szMessage, __FUNCDNAME__, nLogLevel, param1, param2)
```

First I thought that there is some kind of macros overloading and I can easily do it , but turns out if I write another macros with the same name but with different number of argument it wont compile. So to make it work I should make each macros name unique.

So is there are any intelligent way to do this?

Thank you on advance.

Comment: Here's document on `Variadic Macros` of gcc. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: The example given just achieves obfuscation of the code. Why is that obfuscation deemed to be desirable? Should a solution incorporate even greater obfuscation, or just about the same amount of obfuscation but achieved in an "intelligent way" (and what is that)?

Comment: Please post this like an answer, so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `__VA_ARGS__` macro

for example:

```
WriteToLogParamsFunc(const char *__file, int __line, const char* __func, int nLogLevel, const char *szMessage, ...);

#define WriteToLogParams(nLogLevel, szMessage, ...) WriteToLogParamsFunc(__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, nLogLevel, szMessage, __VA_ARGS__ )
```

Comment: Since this is tagged C++, using `...` isn't very C++, specifically, you're losing the type information.

Comment: @avakar: look at the prototype for WriteToLogParamsFunc. I'm sure there are cases where `...` in macro is useful in C++, I don't think it's that common as there are usually better OO ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are some preprocessors that support [variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) but I'm not sure if it's a standard and there definately are compilers that don't support it so it's not portable.

However, instead of trying to have a variable number of parameters, have only one parameter. This is what I have done:-

```
#define WriteToLogParams(args) WriteToLogParamsObject::Instance (__FUNCDNAME__) << args
```

where the WriteToLogParamsObject is a class that is created by the static member `Instance` and has overloaded streaming operators. This gives you the advantages that using these operators has, such as putting streaming overloads into classes:-

```
class SomeClass
{
   static friend WriteToLogParamsObject &operator << (WriteToLogParamsObject &stream, const SomeClass &item_to_log)
   {
     stream << "member1 = " << item_to_log.m_member1 << ", member2 = " << item_to_log.m_member2;
     // and so on (syntax might be off)
     return stream;
   }
 };
```

And to use the macro:-

```
WriteToLogParams ("some message " << some_value << " another bit of text " << another_value << " and so on");
```

Comment: +1 for heading in the right direction. on the downside, missed abstraction opportunities both for the macro and for the `<<` conversions, so that the code shown teaches essentially ungood practice. but, right direction, and in particular not directly *dangerous* and *obfuscated* like the OP's selected "solution".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Do post an answer that addresses your issues, I'd be interested in what good practice is.

Comment: oh, i'm just skimming. i've done my share for the community, so i feel free to not waste more time on that. in comparison, commenting almost takes no time at all :-) and besides i've probably shown these techniques in some other SO answers, as well as on Usenet. google it!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Well, actually, I'm really interested to know as I thought my solution was encompassing OO (in the C++ sense) as it copied the STL's style of streaming (i.e. `cout << stuff` becomes `logging_object << stuff`). The '<<' isn't, to me anyway, doing any conversion (unless there's no suitable overloaded function). The macro merely provides a mechanism for guaranteeing the removal of the code entirely in non-debug builds, i.e `#define WriteToLogParams(args) /* nothing */`. What 'good practice' am I missing?